# Problems in migrating magento to a new server

Tags: magento

I have moved magento to a new server, updated all the database requirments, cleared the cache. but still it is picking up the old database name , userid and password. Thus i cannot connect to my store any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
app/etc/local.xml
var/cache/*
var/session/*
```

Then visit the store URL - you should see the installer (and subsequently complete it).

If you don't see the installer, are you sure you don't have any other applications integrated into your store, eg. Wordpress (which would show "Error establishing database connection" in a big H1)

Answer (score 0):

If your old database is still used, the only possibility is that you did not change the database properties in the file `app/etc/local.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

change var and cache folder permission to 777